# Table measuring using other table

Tags: sql, hive, count, left-join, average

I have two tables in a DB. The tables have an ID column.  One table is always accurate (Table Always) and the other table is sometimes accurate (Table Sometimes). Table Sometimes could have multiple IDs mapping to a single ID on Table Always. Ideally, I want to have a 1-1 mapping between the two tables, but that is not case. How can I come up with an approach to measure Table Sometimes hit/accuracy based on a successful mapping (1 - 1) to Table Always

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate an id-per-id report of the accuracy with a SQL query:

```
select a.id, coalesce(s.cnt, 0) no_matches
from always a
left join (select id, count(*) cnt from sometimes group by id) s 
    on s.id = a.id
```

For each row in table `always`, this checks how many rows match in `sometimes`. Any value other than `1` indicates a mapping problem (either no match at all, or more than one match).

You can the generate summary reports. Say you want the percentage of rows in `a` that have a proper 1-1 match in b:

```
select avg(case when s.cnt = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end) accuracy_ratio
from always a
left join (select id, count(*) cnt from sometimes group by id) s 
    on s.id = a.id
```

Maybe you want to generate three ratios:

```
select 
        avg(case when s.cnt = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end)     accuracy_ratio,
        avg(case when s.cnt is null then 1.0 else 0 end) unmatched_ratio,
        avg(case when s.cnt > 1 then 1.0 else 0 end)     many_matches_ratio,
from always a
left join (select id, count(*) cnt from sometimes group by id) s 
    on s.id = a.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I am still a newbie to SQL. I have a few questions. Is `cnt` an alias for count? what does the `no_matches` do/mean? and what does `b` represent? is it an alias? Apologies if the questions may seem a bit dumb but I want to understand this throughly. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3078335: yes, `cnt` is an alias for the count. `no_matches` stands for "number of matches". `b` is a typo, it should be `s` - I just fixed that.